# Docker Command Issue Running Outside of Bash

Tags: bash, docker

I have a Docker container that handles an application. I am attempting to write tests for my system using `npx` and `nightwatchJS`.

I use CI and to run the tests for my entire suite I `docker-compose build` then run commands from outside of the container like so:

Example of backend python test being called (this works and is run as expected):

`docker-compose run --rm web sh -c "pytest apps/login/tests -s"`

Now I am trying to run an `npx` command to do some front-end testing but I am getting errors with something I cannot seem to diagnose:

> Error while running .navigateTo() protocol action: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. – unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here is that command:

`docker-compose run --rm web sh -c "npx nightwatch apps/login/tests/nightwatch/login_test.js"`

The odd part of this is that if I go into bash:

`docker-compose exec web bash`

And then run:

`npx nightwatch apps/login/tests/nightwatch/login_test.js`

I don't get that error as I'm in bash.

This leads me to believe that I have an error in something with the command. Can somebody please help with this?

Comment: Is you application wanting to connect to `localhost`?

Comment: Yes. It is a Django application with allowed_hosts as 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Think as containers as a separate computers.

When you run on your computer `pytest apps/login/tests -s` and then I run on my computer `npx nightwatch apps/login/tests/nightwatch/login_test.js` surely my computer will not connect to yours. I will get "connection refused" kind of error.

With `docker run` you run a separate new "computer" that runs that command - it has it's own pid space, it's own network address, etc. Than inside "that computer" you can execute another command with `docker exec`. To have you command to connect with localhost, you have to run them on the same "computer".

So when you run `docker run` with the client, it does not connect to a separate `docker run`. Either specify correct ip address or run both commands inside the same container.

I suggest to research how docker works. The above is a very crude oversimplification.

Comment: I'm not sure your explanation makes sense. My tests are not connected so running them in different containers should make no difference. I have about 20 other commands that work this way, the only one that doesn't is the variation with `npx`

Comment: When you `docker run` a new container to run integration tests, `localhost` is the container running the tests, not the separate container running the system under test.

Comment: An idea from this post ended up working. If you add the command `docker-compose exec web bash -c "npx nightwatch apps/login/tests/nightwatch/login_test.js"` in your post I will mark this as accepted.